Are the 'weak' in Joel 3:10 who are to say "I am strong", the people of Judah and Jerusalem - or are they people of the nations whom God will judge?
In Joel 3:4 onwards, God is speaking to Tyre and Sidon of how He will repay them back for the evil they have done. Vs 9 starts with a proclamation to the nations - to prepare and come for war at the valley of Jehoshaphat where God will sit to judge the surrounding nations.

Joel 3:10 - " ... Let the weak say, “I am strong.”

Based on this verse, songs have been written ("and now, let the weak say I am strong, let the poor say I am rich, because of what the Lord has done for me...").
The question is this - are the weak ones who are to say they are strong, the children of Judah and Jerusalem, or the people of the surrounding nations whom God will judge?

Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question and joining the group.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site is different.

Welcome to the Biblical Hermeneutics SE Sherry. We are glad you are here. Please take a moment to take the site tour and check out educating new users and the FAQs. We're passionate about high quality answers. Also consider going through the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.

Sherry, the context of your question could be improved by opening a wider window of the historical context within Joel and maybe an even larger context outside of Joel from the historic time period of where Joel fit in history to help us to understand the surrounding facts related to your isolated question.

According to Joel 3:1, the chapter is a prophecy about, "when I restore Judah and Jerusalem from captivity".  In order to do this, the LORD must remove the barriers for the Jewish return, namely the enemies of God's people - the surrounding nations.
To show/express God's intention, the prophet Joel uses the memory of a great Jewish victory, created by a divine miracle (see 2 Chronicles 20:20-24), against impossible odds - the victory in the Valley of Jehoshaphat.  Note the comment of Ellicott on Joel 3:2 -

The valley of Jehoshaphat.—Some fifty years before Joel prophesied the kingdom of Judah had been menaced by an imposing confederacy of
hostile tribes. It was an occasion of great anxiety. A national fast
was proclaimed, and after it Jehoshaphat engaged and completely routed
the enemy in a valley in the wilderness of Tekoa. (See 2 Chronicles
20) The victory was an occasion of immense exultation, and seems to
supply the imagery with which Joel describes the day of the Lord. The
name of Jehoshaphat was at some period given to the Kedron Valley, but
it is here used rather in its grammatical meaning as the scene of the
Divine judgment, the words signifying “the valley where Jehovah
judgeth.”

Building on the memory of this victory of God, the LORD wants to do the same again by gathering the nations and destroying them in the Valley of Jehoshapht to execute judgement on them.  Thus we read:

V2: I will gather all the nations and bring them down to the Valley of Jehoshaphat. There I will enter into judgment against them concerning My people, My inheritance, Israel, whom they have scattered among the nations as they divided up My land.
V12: Let the nations be roused and advance to the Valley of Jehoshaphat, for there I will sit down to judge all the nations on every side.

This is all a prophecy aimed at restoring Judah and Jerusalem, see V1, V6, V8, V18, V19, V20.  It was in the famous Valley of Jehoshaphat the weak army of Judah won a great victory in the name of the LORD, which he promises to do again and thus prophesies:

V10 - Beat your plowshares into swords and your pruning hooks into
spears. Let the weak say, ‘I am strong!’

Therefore, this prophecy is about the (then) future miracle of returning the exiles to Jerusalem which occurred under king Cyrus in about 537 BC - all the surrounding nations that were enemies had been defeated such as, the Babylonians, the Moabites, the Amorites, the Assyrians, etc.

+1  but so there is no misunderstand the simple answer to the OP's question is "the weak who say they are strong" in this verse are the Gentile nations. God intends for them to be overconfident and to be defeated on that basis.

@DanFefferman - the weak are the peoples of Judah - small and defenseless who became strong in the LORD.
